# Creating objects in android

Tags: java, android

I am having issues with creating objects of a class on android studio. I have created a few classes called Fan, Light and Device.

When i try to instantiate Fan and Light in MainActivity.java I get these errors:

- Field 'myFan' is never used
- Cannot resolve symbol 'breakDevice'

The code is shown below . I'd appreciate any solution to this problem.
Thanks

> MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public Light myLight = new Light();

    Fan myFan = new Fan();

    myFan.breakDevice();
    myLight.breakDevice();
}
```

> Fan.java

```
package com.example.codealong3;

import android.util.Log;

public class Fan extends Device{

    public Fan() {
        setDeviceName("FAN");
    }

    @Override
    public void breakDevice() {
        Log.e(getDeviceName(), "BANG ! It's broken");
    }
}
```

> Light.java

```
package com.example.codealong3;

import android.util.Log;

public class Light extends Device {

    public Light() {
        setDeviceName("LIGHT");
    }

    @Override
    public void breakDevice() {
        Log.e(getDeviceName(), "Glass Everywhere! .. I guess that's not bad");
    }
}
```

Comment: you should call your ` myFan.breakDevice();
    myLight.breakDevice();` in some method like you do it in `onCreate()`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

> MainActivity.java

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity 
    {

        public Light myLight = new Light();

        Fan myFan = new Fan();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            myFan.breakDevice();

            myLight.breakDevice();  
      }    

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've created the objects as fields fine.

You cannot call instance methods outside of any other methods, though, so you have to use break device within onCreate, or as part of a button click event, for example

Comment: FWIW, don't use Android log methods as part of POJO classes

Answer (score 0):

Instantiation is correct but you can only access methods of an object inside methods, not on class level.

You can access it inside the onCreate method as sampled by A Maharaja or another method.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    //Instantiate object on global or class level
    public Light myLight = new Light();
    Fan myFan = new Fan();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        executeObjectCommands();
    }

    //You can execute your commands inside this method
    //You can also separate them in different methods and return something if needed
    public void executeObjectCommands()
    {
        myFan.breakDevice();
        myLight.breakDevice();
    }
}
```